# python 3.6 не принимает sumrange.exe как приложение Win32!

Tags: python

Мой вопрос почему я получаю сообщение, что sumrange.exe не является приложением Win32?

Python выдает ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\tmp\py\e2.py", line 2, in <module>
    sumrange_ctypes = ctypes.CDLL('.\sumrange.exe').sumrange
  File "C:\Users\ustav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36       \lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 не является приложением Win32
```

в скрипте

```
import ctypes
sumrange_ctypes = ctypes.CDLL('.\sumrange.exe').sumrange
sumrange_ctypes.restype = ctypes.c_ulonglong
sumrange_ctypes.argtypes = ctypes.c_ulonglong
```

где есть ссылка на sumrange.exe,
полученный при помощи команды
    gcc -o c:\tmp\py\sumrange c:\tmp\py\sumrange.c

---

Я сделал DLL при помощи "gcc -shared -o sumrange.dll sumrange.c", но python все равно сообщает, что sumrange.dll не является элементом приложения Win32!!!

Comment: вы вероятно хотите спросить "как скомпилировать dll на с помощью gcc на Windows" и "как воспользоваться функцией из dll на Windows с помощью ctypes" Связанный вопрос: [Building a DLL with MinGW and loading it with Python's ctypes module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16630215/4279)

Comment: А у этого EXE экспорты-то вообще есть?

Comment: Какая у вас разрядность операционной системы, интерпретатора Python и компилятора GCC?

Answer (score 1):

Конструктор [ctypes.CDLL()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.CDLL), как и следует из его названия, принимает имя [динамически подключаемой библиотеки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0) (dll), а не исполняемого файла (exe). Соответственно, вам нужно скомпилировать библиотеку:

```
gcc -shared -o sumrange.dll sumrange.c
```